# librecalc showing wrong time numbers

Tags: cell-format

ok so i have this

```
43.26
55.45
1:16.82
1:44.43
2:18.66
2:44.57
3:18.00
3:46.63
4:17.53
4:45.09
```

but when i input them into libre calc the first 2 are wrong. i get this as a result when formating to `Time 37:46.00`

```
14:24.00
48:00.00
01:16.82
01:44.43
02:18.66
02:44.57
03:18.00
03:46.63
04:17.53
04:45.09
```

how do i get this to convert corectly?

Comment: Surely this is a data input problem.  How many cells do you have to correct and how often.

Comment: about 10 whenever speedrunners update their times. so if anything is under a min it does random stuff. and i found out that if i convert it all to time the an `'` gets put in the front of all the times that it wants a `0` to be.

Answer (score 0):

Enter `43.26` as `0:43.26` so that LibreOffice Calc treats the value as a time stamp.

Comment: this works but i was looking for a solution that didn't have me edit it myself.